# Change printer settings in reports

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

When I update my Access application, I need to change printer settings on each PC - matching the attached labelprinters name, using a specific predefined label on each printer and then adjust the margins.
I would like to automate that process. But I'm having problems getting the reports to save the settings.

The idea is to export the printer settings to a table (done), update the application and then read the "old" settings for each report and save it as a part of the update.

Problem is, that I can't get Access 2010 to save the settings.

Any ideas?

```vb
Dim rpt As Access.Report
Dim rstUpdRptSettings As ADODB.Recordset
Dim NameOfPrinter As String

Set rstUpdRptSettings = New ADODB.Recordset

rstUpdRptSettings.Open "Select * From tblUpdRptSettings", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Do While Not rstUpdRptSettings.EOF
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:=rstUpdRptSettings!ReportName, View:=acViewDesign, WindowMode:=acHidden
    Set rpt = Reports(rstUpdRptSettings!ReportName)
    NameOfPrinter = rstUpdRptSettings!PrinterName

    With rpt
        .Printer = Application.Printers(NameOfPrinter)
        .Printer.TopMargin = rstUpdRptSettings!TopMargin
        .Printer.BottomMargin = rstUpdRptSettings!BottomMargin
        .Printer.LeftMargin = rstUpdRptSettings!LeftMargin
        .Printer.RightMargin = rstUpdRptSettings!RightMargin
        .Printer.PaperSize = rstUpdRptSettings!PaperSize
    End With
    DoCmd.Close acReport, rpt.Name, acSaveYes
    rstUpdRptSettings.MoveNext
Loop
```

Running the code does not change any settings - nor printer name, margins or PaperSize.

Comment: `rpt.Printer` is an object, not a value. So you need `Set .Printer = Application.Printers(NameOfPrinter)`. Not sure if this is the only problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comment.

I have solved the problem now by adding this to the code:

```
If .DefaultView = 0 Then
    .DefaultView = 1
Else
    .DefaultView = 0
End If
'Set it back
If .DefaultView = 0 Then
    .DefaultView = 1
Else
    .DefaultView = 0
End If
```

I found the explanation and code here (thanks to Daniel):
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8061fb4a-2e5f-4abe-a1ab-493c3d733e82/set-report-margins-using-vba?forum=accessdev

Answered by:
Daniel Pineault, 2010-2016 Microsoft MVP 
Professional Support: http://www.cardaconsultants.com 
MS Access Tips and Code Samples: http://www.devhut.net

Comment: Interesting. Please add relevant parts from the forum thread to your answer, in case the link dies. You already have the attribution. -- Note: you could do `.DefaultView = 1 - .DefaultView` instead of the If/Else.

Comment: Andre - thats true.
Daniel: "This is the oddest thing. If you step through your code and check the page setup the values are properly applied. It is specifically the Save process that isn't working properly! What you have to do, and I've tested, is you need to change any report property to another value, then set it back to what it was and then proceed with your close and save. Basically Access doesn't seem the recognize the margin changes as having changed the report so your save does not actually save anything. By making a dummy change, it will then see that things changes and save it all."